# tkinter Scrollable frame only scrolling last added page in notebook using mouse wheel

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to make an app with tabs. I will have lots of buttons on tab so I need a scrollable frame on each tab. Below is the code I have taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/mp035/9f2027c3ef9172264532fcd6262f3b01):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# ************************
# Scrollable Frame Class
# ************************
class ScrollFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent) # create a frame (self)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")          #place canvas on self
        self.viewPort = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")                    #place a frame on the canvas, this frame will hold the child widgets 
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview) #place a scrollbar on self 
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)                          #attach scrollbar action to scroll of canvas

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")                                       #pack scrollbar to right of self
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)                     #pack canvas to left of self and expand to fil
        self.canvas_window = self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.viewPort, anchor="nw",            #add view port frame to canvas
                                  tags="self.viewPort")

        self.viewPort.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)                       #bind an event whenever the size of the viewPort frame changes.
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.onCanvasConfigure)                       #bind an event whenever the size of the viewPort frame changes.
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.onScroll)                       #bind an event whenever the size of the viewPort frame changes.

        self.onFrameConfigure(None)                                                 #perform an initial stretch on render, otherwise the scroll region has a tiny border until the first resize
        

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):                                              
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))                 #whenever the size of the frame changes, alter the scroll region respectively.

    def onCanvasConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the canvas window to encompass inner frame when required'''
        canvas_width = event.width
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.canvas_window, width = canvas_width)            #whenever the size of the canvas changes alter the window region respectively.
    def onScroll(self,event):
        if event.state == 0:
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")
            return "break"
        elif event.state == 1:
            self.canvas.xview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")
            return "break"


# ********************************
# Example usage of the above class
# ********************************

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.scrollFrame = ScrollFrame(self) # add a new scrollable frame.
        
        # Now add some controls to the scrollframe. 
        # NOTE: the child controls are added to the view port (scrollFrame.viewPort, NOT scrollframe itself)
        for row in range(100):
            a = row
            tk.Label(self.scrollFrame.viewPort, text="%s" % row, width=3, borderwidth="1", 
                     relief="solid").grid(row=row, column=0)
            t="this is the second column for row %s" %row
            tk.Button(self.scrollFrame.viewPort, text=t, command=lambda x=a: self.printMsg("Hello " + str(x))).grid(row=row, column=1)

        # when packing the scrollframe, we pack scrollFrame itself (NOT the viewPort)
        self.scrollFrame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    
    def printMsg(self, msg):
        print(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    main_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    nb = ttk.Notebook(main_frame)
    frame = Example(nb) 
    #frame = tk.Frame(main_frame)
    frame.pack()
    nb.add(frame,text = "frame1")
    frame1 = Example(nb) 
    frame1.pack()
    nb.add(frame1,text = "frame2")
    nb.pack(side = "left")
    main_frame.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

The problem is I am able to scroll only the last added tab in the notebook with mouse wheel. The scrollable frame works as expected for single tab. But when multiple tabs are added I am only able to scroll last added tab through mouse wheel.

Comment: When I ran your code the scrolling is working in both tab but when the mouse is inside the scrollbar

Comment: Yes, it is working only when mouse is inside the scrollbar. I want it to work when mouse is on the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like issue with the bind_all call on canvas widget, the bind_all is replacing the callback every time it is called in the ScrollableFrame. I have used bindtags and bind_class for each tab to separate callbacks. Below is updated code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# ************************
# Scrollable Frame Class
# ************************
class ScrollFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent,frame_name):
        super().__init__(parent) # create a frame (self)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")          #place canvas on self
        self.viewPort = tk.Frame(self.canvas, background="#ffffff")                    #place a frame on the canvas, this frame will hold the child widgets 
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview) #place a scrollbar on self 
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)                          #attach scrollbar action to scroll of canvas

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")                                       #pack scrollbar to right of self
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)                     #pack canvas to left of self and expand to fil
        self.canvas_window = self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.viewPort, anchor="nw",            #add view port frame to canvas
                                  tags="self.viewPort")

        self.viewPort.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)                       #bind an event whenever the size of the viewPort frame changes.
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", self.onCanvasConfigure)                       #bind an event whenever the size of the viewPort frame changes.
        self.viewPort.bindtags((frame_name,)+(self.viewPort.bindtags()))
        self.viewPort.bind_class(frame_name,"<MouseWheel>", self.onScroll)                       #bind an event whenever the size of the viewPort frame changes.

        self.onFrameConfigure(None)                                                 #perform an initial stretch on render, otherwise the scroll region has a tiny border until the first resize
        

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):                                              
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))                 #whenever the size of the frame changes, alter the scroll region respectively.

    def onCanvasConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the canvas window to encompass inner frame when required'''
        canvas_width = event.width
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.canvas_window, width = canvas_width)            #whenever the size of the canvas changes alter the window region respectively.
    def onScroll(self,event):
        print(event)
        if event.state == 0:
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")
            return "break"
        elif event.state == 1:
            self.canvas.xview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")
            return "break"


# ********************************
# Example usage of the above class
# ********************************

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root,frame):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.scrollFrame = ScrollFrame(self,frame) # add a new scrollable frame.
        
        # Now add some controls to the scrollframe. 
        # NOTE: the child controls are added to the view port (scrollFrame.viewPort, NOT scrollframe itself)
        for row in range(100):
            a = row
            label = tk.Label(self.scrollFrame.viewPort, text="%s" % row, width=3, borderwidth="1", 
                     relief="solid")
            label.grid(row=row, column=0)
            label.bindtags((frame,)+(label.bindtags()))
            t="this is the second column for row %s" %row
            
            button = tk.Button(self.scrollFrame.viewPort, text=t, command=lambda x=a: self.scrollFrame.canvas.yview_scroll(1,"units"))
            button.grid(row=row, column=1)
            button.bindtags((frame,)+(button.bindtags()))

        # when packing the scrollframe, we pack scrollFrame itself (NOT the viewPort)
        self.scrollFrame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    
    def printMsg(self, msg):
        print(msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    main_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    nb = ttk.Notebook(main_frame)
    frame1 = Example(nb,"frame1")
    frame1.pack()
    nb.add(frame1,text = "frame1")
    frame2 = Example(nb,"frame2") 
    frame2.pack()
    nb.add(frame2,text = "frame2")
    nb.pack(side = "left")
    main_frame.pack()
    root.bind_all("<FocusIn>", lambda e : print(root.focus_get(),flush=True))
    root.mainloop()
```